# Why AppFabric caching features are only supported for a domain environment?

Tags: .net, appfabric

On [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790954.aspx) MSDN article you can see (at the end of the page) that caching features are not supported on production environments for worgroups.

What's exaclty not supported? I mean, if you can set it up for workgroups on a test environment it means that is possible. I'm not sure if it's not recommended or some features won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

**only supported** is unclear, it could mean it won't work but since it works in development and test I would imagine it would also work in prod but being unsupported if you have a problem MS does not care/help/mind.

In general I would say, do you know any Windows server based **production environment** where servers are in a workgroup without AD enabled!? I have never seen this.

Comment: Yeah, I know one. The one where I'm supposed to deploy appfabric :)